# Submit just one of many forms (same name, different IDs) using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have list of recently uploaded files, which have editable inputs. Every item of a list is wrapped in a form with its submit button. I want to edit these inputs and submit particular form (which saves changes to db) using Ajax and serialized form.

Problem is, ajax is not sucessfull with its POST method, and I can't figure out why. In minimalised HTML example are only 2 forms containing one hidden input. In reality, there could by much more forms and each of them have many inputs type text, selects, ...

In JS, I get `id` of `<form>` element after clicking its submit button. Then the  `form` with the `id` is submited, it should serialize form and send it to PHP. But after I click on submit button, console reports "failed" because Ajax was not successful. When I comment line `e.preventDefault();`, form is being sent noramlly and $id is displayed correctly thanks to echo.

I was not able to solve it on my own nor find a solution here, so I ask here for your help. I belive this is not a complex problem and I just do not know what I am doing :) Thanks.

**Edit:** I have updated JS - got rid of click event, edited success function and added `error:` in `$.ajax`. It shows no error. It should now log `$id` in console, but it logs only blank line (so nothing).

```html
<form name="save-image" id="save-image-74" action="./inc/upload-proc.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="save-image-id" value="74">
  <input type="submit" name="save-image" value="Save">'
</form>

<form name="save-image" id="save-image-75" action="./inc/upload-proc.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="save-image-id" value="75">
  <input type="submit" name="save-image" value="Save">'
</form>
```

Javascript + jQuery:

```js
// Send SAVE IMAGE form with Ajax
$("form[name*='save-image']").submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(form);
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
           alert(err.Message);
         },
         success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
        }
       });
  });
```

upload-proc.php:

```js
if (isset($_POST['save-image'])) {
  $id = $_POST['save-image-id'];
  // There will be updates in database, not important.
  echo $id;
}
```

Comment: I think this article may help you out https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata essentially you need to make use of FormData

Comment: Log the response data instead. Your test for success/fail doesn't make sense. Use error handler to take care of ajax failure

Comment: Also don't create a submit event listener inside the click listener. Get rid of click listener completely and replace with `$('form').submit(.... var url= this.action.....`

Comment: @charlietfl    Well, i need to get `id` of form being submited, thats why it is inside click listener. Do you have better solution?

Comment: Can get form id inside form submit handler `this.id`. Don't think you understand will take 2 clicks to submit the form because of the way you apply the listener. Just  really bad practice to do it that way

Comment: Also the only reason you get the form ID in code shown is just an extra useless step . You traverse up to the form....get the id from that form element just so you can create an id selector to get the same element again that you already had reference to in previous line

Comment: @charlietfl     Thank you for your effort, but I'm afraid I dont understand. `form.submit()` immediatly submits the `form`. It actually takes one click even inside click handler. But without click handler, `form` is not defined. I have many forms with same name and same name of submit button. I need to select it by `id` before submiting. Real structure is bit more complicated, submit button is in sepparate div so that why I traverse in parent elements.

Comment: You don't need the id just to get the form. You are just over-complicating this and nesting listener inside another event handler needlessly. Doing that is a bad practice and can lead to hard to find bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have found what the problem is. I'm sure it is obvious for you, but it is new to me. I thought .serialize() posts form name itself to upload-proc.php, but it probably only sends its inputs. So instead of `if (isset($_POST['save-image'])) { ... }`, I should use name of hidden input, so correct upload-proc.php is:

```
if (isset($_POST['save-image-id'])) {
  $id = $_POST['save-image-id'];
  // There will be updates in database, not important.
  echo $id;
}
```